# Why is ".map" slower then "while/for loop" in Dart(Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, functional-programming

I saw this article:
https://itnext.io/comparing-darts-loops-which-is-the-fastest-731a03ad42a2

It says that ".map" is slow with benchmark result

But I don't understand why slower than while/for loop

How does it work in low level?

I think it's because `.map` is called an unnamed method like this `(_){ }`

Can you explain that in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you explain that in detail?

It's like saying "I don't understand why hitchhiking on the back of a construction truck is so much slower than taking the high speed train to my destination".

The only detail that is important is that **map is *not* a loop**. [`map()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) internally probably *uses* a loop of some kind.

This person is misusing a method call that is meant for something else, just because a **side-effect** of that call *when combining it with a call materializing the iterable, like* `toList()`, is that it loops through the iterable given. It doesn't even have the side effect on it's own.

Stop reading "tutorials" or "tips" of people misusing language features. `map()` is not a loop. If you need a loop, use a loop. The same goes for the ternary operator. It's not an `if`, if you need an `if`, use it.

Use language features for what they are meant, stop misusing language features because their *side-effect* does what you want and then wondering why they don't work as well as the feature actually meant for it.

Sorry if this seems a bit ranty, but I have seen countless examples by now. I don't know where it comes from. My personal guess is "internet tutorials". Because everybody can write one. Please don't read them. Read a good book. It was written by professionals, proofread, edited, and checked. Internet tutorials are free, written by random people and about worth as much as they cost.

Comment: You are right. That article is actually using .toList(), The inside map() is no different from the others loop Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Its because mapping an array will create a copy of each value than modify the original array.

Since a while/for loop does not copy the values but rather just accesses them using their index, it is a lot faster.

Comment: You also can infer that the time is dominated by constructing a new `List` and not from the anonymous function invocation by comparing the results from `.map` vs `.forEach` (which also uses a callback).